# How to concat string in mysql?

Tags: mysql

WHat i want is concate the static string to dataset i want to add string as min, avg, max to the fetched data. when i m trying give some error?

my query

```
select m.medTitle, 
min(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, s.dmtViewStart, s.dmtViewEnd)) playtime
from tbldoctormediatracktest s
left join tblmedia m on s.dmtMedId = m.medId
group by m.medTitle
union all
select m.medTitle, 
avg(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, s.dmtViewStart, s.dmtViewEnd)) playtime
from tbldoctormediatracktest s
left join tblmedia m on s.dmtMedId = m.medId
group by m.medTitle
union all
select m.medTitle, 
  max(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, s.dmtViewStart, s.dmtViewEnd)) playtime
from tbldoctormediatracktest s
left join tblmedia m
  on s.dmtMedId = m.medId
group by m.medTitle
order by medTitle,  playtime;
```

what i am trying.

```
select concat(m.medTitle,'minimum'), 
  min(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, s.dmtViewStart, s.dmtViewEnd)) playtime
from tbldoctormediatracktest s
left join tblmedia m
  on s.MedId = m.MedId
group by m.medTitle
union all

select concat(m.medTitle,'average'), 
  avg(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, s.dmtViewStart, s.dmtViewEnd)) playtime
from tbldoctormediatracktest s
left join tblmedia m
  on s.MedId = m.MedId
group by m.medTitle
union all

select concat(m.medTitle,'maximum'),  
  max(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, s.dmtViewStart, s.dmtViewEnd)) playtime
from tbldoctormediatracktest s
left join tblmedia m
  on s.MedId = m.MedId
group by m.medTitle
order by medTitle,  playtime
```

Comment: Both your queries doesn't compile. Either post a valid query and state what you want to change, or show us the tables structure and the requested output.

Comment: Can you tell us the error you got?

Comment: see my this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465825/how-to-get-min-max-and-avg-from-table-in-mysql-with-different-rows
and
 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf37a/9
in this example first records for casfung are there 
i just want to add min, avg , max to casfung
result date like
casfung(min)
casfung(avg)
casfung(max)

Comment: Error Unknown column 'medTitle' in 'order clause': select concat(m.medTitle,'minimum'), min(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, s.dmtViewStart, s.dmtViewEnd)) playtime from tbldoctormediatracktest s left join tblmedia m on s.MedId = m.MedId group by m.medTitle union all select concat(m.medTitle,'average'), avg(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, s.dmtViewStart, s.dmtViewEnd)) playtime from tbldoctormediatracktest s left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
select playtime,type 
from(
select m.MedId, 
  min(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, s.dmtViewStart, s.dmtViewEnd)) playtime,
  concat(m.medTitle,' (minimum)') as type
from tbldoctormediatracktest s
left join tblmedia m
  on s.MedId = m.MedId
group by m.MedId
union all

select m.MedId, 
  avg(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, s.dmtViewStart, s.dmtViewEnd)) playtime,
  concat(m.medTitle,' (average)') as type
from tbldoctormediatracktest s
left join tblmedia m
  on s.MedId = m.MedId
group by m.MedId
union all

select m.MedId,  
  max(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, s.dmtViewStart, s.dmtViewEnd)) playtime,
  concat(m.medTitle,' (maximum)') as type 
from tbldoctormediatracktest s
left join tblmedia m
  on s.MedId = m.MedId
group by m.MedId)a
order by MedId,  playtime
```

## [SQL Fiddle domo 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf37a/29)

## [SQl Fiddle Demo 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf37a/30)

## [SQL Fiddle Demo 3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf37a/31)

Comment: can we group by and order by  m.MedId?

Comment: you want 78 Casfung (maximum) in the ouptput?

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(m.medTitle, 'min') medTitle,
  min(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, s.dmtViewStart, s.dmtViewEnd)) playtime
from tbldoctormediatracktest s
left join tblmedia m
  on s.MedId = m.MedId
group by m.medTitle

union all

select concat(m.medTitle, 'avg') medTitle, 
  avg(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, s.dmtViewStart, s.dmtViewEnd)) playtime
from tbldoctormediatracktest s
left join tblmedia m
  on s.MedId = m.MedId
group by m.medTitle

union all

select m.medTitle || 'max' medTitle, 
  max(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, s.dmtViewStart, s.dmtViewEnd)) playtime
from tbldoctormediatracktest s
left join tblmedia m
  on s.MedId = m.MedId
group by m.medTitle
order by medTitle, playtime
```

Updated your query from the link.
I noticed that you need to give the alias for m.medTitle after concatenating.

Any of `concat(m.medTitle, 'min')` or `m.medTitle || 'min'` can be used for concatenation.

Comment: this min max avg should add as suffix. suppose first record comes as 'boxer' then min should be added to boxer like boxermin. sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27a4b/8

Comment: some how you got my problem but not returning last query value max

Comment: You can update the concatenated string. I did 'min' for all the three queries. Anyway, updated my answer again.

Comment: can we group by and order by m.MedId?